# JOGL throws errors in atio6axx.dll

Tags: opengl, driver, jogl

In attempting to do some OpenGL development using JOGL, I persistently get the following error:

```
# Problematic frame:
# C  [atio6axx.dll+0x73a32]
```

Hunting around the web pointed this squarely at AMD video drivers, and strongly suggests that updating my drivers was in order.

Problem: 
I have an HP Pavilion dv6-3206ax, which has actually TWO GPUs on board, one high-power and fast, the low power and assumably slower.
The standard AMD Catalyst installation doesn't like this configuration, so I can only use the drivers from the HP support site.

The video card(s) are:
ATI Mobility Radeon HD 6550 and
AMD M880G with ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4250

NB: I *can* force the latest drivers for the 6550 to install by navigating to the AMD Radeon display driver directory, and that does allow JOGL to run. But it also causes my laptop to overheat.

They haven't been updated in two years, and I already have the latest. Help?

Answer (score 0):

I had to downgrade my AMD graphics driver to [20.4.2](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-rad-win-20-4-2)

Answer (score -1):

I have found a solution of sorts.
If I use the ATI PowerXpress to manually select the "Power Saving GPU", OpenGL works.
This is good enough for my purposes at the moment.

I had to download and install the latest AMD High-Definition Graphics Driver from the HP Support site to get ATI PowerXPress to work at all.

Answer (score -1):

Try what this chap did, from the section of 'manually uninstall drivers'.

What a legend!
http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/6794729581

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem on my Lenovo Legion 5 laptop model specifically according to AMD Adrenaline software "AMD Ryzen 7 6800H with Radeon Graphics".

My Java code using JOGL 2.5.0 would crash with access violation exception outside JVM in *atio6axx.dll* on calling `GLProfile.getDefault()` if I had an external HDMI monitor plugged in.

I finally solved it by installing the latest *AMD Adrenaline 23.12.1* which was found automatically using the AMD automatic detection tool from https://www.amd.com/en/support/apu/amd-ryzen-processors/amd-ryzen-7-mobile-processors-radeon-graphics/amd-ryzen-7-6800h. Specifically it downloaded *amd-software-adrenalin-edition-23.12.1-minimalsetup-231205_web.exe* which ran and eventually installed the updated AMD GPU driver.

During the install, it offered to install a bunch of chipset drivers. I skipped those thinking (maybe incorrectly) that it might mess up or conflict with Lenovo drivers.

Anyhow now it is working, so I guess AMD fixed this driver bug.