# Errors outside JVM in file atio6axx.dll+0x193b60

Tags: java, intellij-idea, driver, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am setting up a minecraft mod in IntelliJ in forge version 1.19.2-43.2.12. When I try to run the game from IntelliJ, I get the error message:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffb6cda2b60, pid=8868, tid=8924
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.7+7 (17.0.7+7) (build 17.0.7+7)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.7+7 (17.0.7+7, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [atio6axx.dll+0x192b60]
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

atio6axx.dll is a driver file in Windows System32. I have reinstalled all graphic drivers and updated Windows 10 to its newest version. I use a Radeon RX 570, and I've uninstalled AMD Adrenalin and AMD chipset. My IntelliJ is running on the newest 2023 Community version.
I tried Java 8 and Java 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been several threads relating to this issue on the Forge forums. (See [here](https://forums.minecraftforge.net/topic/114940-jvm-access-violation-exception-119/), [here](https://forums.minecraftforge.net/topic/117925-forge-1192-43147-crashing-on-startup-with-exit-code-1) and [here](https://forums.minecraftforge.net/topic/119038-1192-failed-to-run-example-mod-on-fresh-setup/)). You said you tried reinstalling your graphic drivers, but not updating them. I would try updating to the latest first. If that doesn't work, try downgrading as people in the aforementioned Forge threads have done and reported success.

> I tried Java 8 and Java 17.

Minecraft 1.18+ requires Java 17+, so you don't need to test with Java 8.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338757/jogl-throws-errors-in-atio6axx-dll